# MurmurHash function does not behave deterministic

Tags: c++, c, hash

I am using a murmurhash function in C/C++ like the one proposed here: https://sites.google.com/site/murmurhash/ (MurmurHash2.cpp). I am invoking this method multiple times on different keys. The behaviour is not deterministic, though. Sometimes for the same key, I get different results (same key, same len, same seed, different return value). I debugged it and it seems that there is a difference from the following line:

```
line 33: unsigned int k = *(unsigned int *)data;
```

After that line, there are different k values for the same input of the method, which then causes also the final h that is returned to be different.

Did I misunderstand something? What could be the issues causing this behaviour?
Thanks in advance!

Some more details about the invocation:

The call comes from Lua code, the Lua code invokes a C function with the following signature:

```
int preparehash(lua_State *L)
```

This function then reads the parameters from the Lua stack and invokes the following function which is using MurmurHash2:

```
unsigned int hashing(const char *a, unsigned int seed) {
        int len = (int)sizeof(a);
        unsigned int b = MurmurHash2(a,len,seed);
        return b;
}
```

Comment: `int len = (int)sizeof(a);` is almost certainly wrong. That should probably use `strlen(a)`.

Comment: as a matter of fact, murmur hash produces the same hashes for the same input data. Could it be that this time, it is not the whole world that is wrong, but instead the way you feed it with data is somehow feeding it with different data sometimes, e.g. due to an oversight like hashing padding values too.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show us the type of `data`, but that line

```
unsigned int k = *(unsigned int *)data;
```

looks fundamentally wrong and could explain why you see different values. If `data` is of different width than `unsigned int` or aligned differently, some bytes of `k` may receive some garbage that just happens to be in the high word at `*data`.